# Custom Dimensions in Google Analytics iOS

Tags: ios, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have implemented 3 user level custom dimensions in Google Analytics iOS for my app in the following manner:

```
[tracker send:[[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createAppView] set:[DeviceType deviceType] forKey:[GAIFields customDimensionForIndex:1]] build]];
[tracker send:[[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createAppView] set:[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] forKey:[GAIFields customDimensionForIndex:2]] build]];
[tracker send:[[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createAppView] set:fullVersionUser forKey:[GAIFields customDimensionForIndex:3]] build]];
```

I've set up the dimensions properly in the control panel and all 3 list as active. I'm just wondering, how do I simply view these dimensions? I've tried generating a custom report and nothing seems to show. Is there anyway to make these dimensions appear in the regular report?

Comment: *Google Analytics has always been too much confusing! I wish Flurry gets better after Yahoo acquisition!*

Comment: @rohan-patel - Yeah there is so much stuff you can do with it, it's overwhelming. I probably not even using it properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was that I was executing the above line of code in the app delegate where I wasn't setting a screen view. When I changed the code to the following:

```
[tracker send:[[[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createAppView] set:@"App Delegate"  forKey:kGAIScreenName] set:[DeviceType deviceType] forKey:[GAIFields customDimensionForIndex:1]] build]];
```

it worked. You could also move the code to a view controller that subclasses `GAITrackedViewController` and does:

```
self.screenName = @"some screen name";
```

Comment: may I know what is the second set: for? the `set:[DeviceType deviceType] forKey:[GAIFields customDimensionForIndex:1]]` particularly... Thanks!

Comment: @Zennichimaro That is to give the specific device model, i.e. iphone5s, iphone4, ipad, etc.

Comment: @CoDEFRo I am wondering where can you see this custom dimensions on DashBoard?

Comment: I meant were you able to see anything related to this part :`set:[DeviceType deviceType] forKey:[GAIFields customDimensionForIndex:1]`in dashboard?

Comment: @rohan-patel - On the side panel, go to Events -> Top Events, then click "Secondary Dimension" which is just above the title "Event Action" and you'll see Custom Dimensions there.

Comment: Thanks. That was hard to figure out by myself. But I see custom variables under *Secondary Dimension* not custom dimensions. They both are different, I believe.